# Doctrine2: Insertion of an entity in a single inheritance table fashion without knowing in advance the entity type

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have several entities in a Single Inheritance Table policy, and there's no way to tell Doctrine which one to pick without knowing it in advance (i.e. new ClassA() or new ClassB() or...)

So, someone can suggest me how to handle the insertion of an entity in a single inheritance table fashion without knowing in advance the entity type (user choice)? (AbstractFactory maybe?)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here. You should know what sort of entity you are creating before you create it. Can you show us your entities?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: I understand how the difference forms of inheritance work in Doctrine. What we really need to be able to help you is to see the entities and to understand why you can't determine which entity you need until after it is inserted in to the database. I suspect your design could be improved to avoid the problem altogether. As it is there isn't enough information for me to be able to help you.